# An unexpected error occurred in the IBM DB2, IDS, and U2 Data Provider for .NET Framework

Tags: .net, db2, dataprovider

When i try to install latest beta tools for Visual Studio 2010 (from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=345634&tstart=0)) i get the following error:

> An unexpected error occurred in the
>   IBM DB2, IDS, and U2 Data Provider for
>   .NET Framework. Please contact the
>   provider vendor to resolve this
>   problem.

What am i doing wrong?!
**Steps(evrth is version 9.7fp3a):**
**1**-I install IBM Data Server Runtime client
**2**-I install IBM Data Server Driver Package
**3**-IBM.NETProviders4.0Beta-64bit - unpack and run as its written in readme. Seems that evrth here is nice and it copies dlls into driver directory, changes machine.config for frameworks and registers assemblies in GAC
**4**-IBM.NETVSAI4.0Beta run the setup bat file it says "success", and disappears after some time.

After all that i run VS2010 and try to add new connection in Server Explorer.

> The exception An unexpected error
>   occurred in the IBM DB2, IDS, an...

occurs here.
OS: windows 7x64.
Please tell me what am i doing wrong.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer at IBM's forums: 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=356324&tstart=0

**UPDATE: check the updated version of fixpack. Seems that IBM fixed many bugs in providers**
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=368836&tstart=0